# how to get already initialized instances from an ILifetimeScope?

Tags: c#, autofac

currently we have `ILifetimeScope.ComponentRegistry` for getting registered classes and interfaces but I need to get the **already** initialized instances of the registered classes, how do I do that in autofac?

for example in one class it gets an instance of `IImageType` like so:

```
public class ImageResizer {
    public ImageResizer(IImageType imageType)
    {
        // at this point an instance of IImageType is probably stored in Autofac somewhere
    }
}

public class ImageScaler {
    public ImageScaler(IImageType imageType)
    {
        // at this point an instance of IImageType is probably stored in Autofac somewhere
    }
}
```

now I need to get all instances of all interfaces initialized including all the `IImageType` initialized, not the registered type, I need the initialized object itself

Comment: What is the purpose? Because it sounds like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Actually what you currently have as well.

Comment: @freakish so basically I have classes that implements basically 2 interfaces lets say IService and IImageResizer services, now not all the time these 2 interfaces are implemented on the same class, sometimes a class implements IService and IAudioCutter but I dont want to manually register IImageResizer and IAudioCutter because there are many other interfaces but ALL are an IService, so basically I just register them as IService and I cannot put IImageResizer in the constructor because it has to be IService

Comment: I used ContainerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes to register all instances across the assembly and I only register IService because there are too many classes, the project is very big

Comment: Now I implemented an interface IStoppable which has a function called Stop() and I need to find all classes that implements IStoppable accross all registered instance that also implements IService, current my problem is that ILifetimeScope.Resolve creates a new instance which what I need is the ALREADY generated instance.

Comment: Let me get this straight: is your problem that you have too many classes and you don't want to manually register them? Then you can simply scan your assembly (via reflection, also I think autofac has its own scanning tools) and register each class for all interfaces it implements. That solves your first problem, correct?

Comment: For the second problem, one of the possibilities is to have a IStoppableRegistry interface with `.Register(IStoppable obj)` method. Then your every IStoppable class should have it as dependency and register itself. With that you can Stop them by working with the IStoppableRegistry only. This is what you want, except requires more manual work.

Comment: @freakish yes that is correct, I have IService on about 100+ classes, basically it's a Discord bot and all these classes handle commands, I simply can't register one service for example a class has IService and IImageResizer on it and another has IService and IAudioCutter on it. Also classes that can be stopped has IStoppable on it.

Comment: Why can't you register these classes via `.AsImplementedInterfaces()`? And then use appropriate interfaces where needed? Or maybe: why the dependency has to be `IService`? That sounds weird.

Comment: Oh, wow, that fixed the entire thing haha

Comment: So if that solves your issue, then you can delete the question. Because it is no longer valid. Good luck. :)